# Get the AccountId in the callout Apex class (below)

Tags: apex, callout, child-to-parent, apexpage

@all,

In the below apex class I need to get the related AccountId from the custom child class "Pending_address__c", tried multiple times but is shows null value, currently I am hardcoding it as acountId, Can you please provide the solution to it?

APEX CLASS

```
public with sharing class getAddressInfo {
    
    public final Pending_Address__c acct;
    public string accId {get;set;}
    public Id recId{get;set;}
    //public Id accountId{get;set;}
    private final Account{get;set;}
      
    Id acountId = '0011k00000gXufLAAS';
    String authToken = 'Token c97989077db09971617fde1962911fa7858e8a8ff1ee861264c29c583d6d6d25';
  
public getAddressInfo(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
   
Account account = [SELECT Account__r.id FROM Pending_Address__c WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

    
     /*   this.acct =(Pending_Address__c) stdController.getRecord();

     if(accountId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName() == 'Account'){
            Account[] acc = [SELECT ID FROM Account Where ID =:accountId];
            if (acc.size() > 0){
                recId = acc[0].Id;
                system.debug('id is '+recId);
            }
         } 
    // getaddressCallout();

ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(this.acct);
    
    String str =this.acct.Id;  */
}     
    
    
    
    public ResponseGetAddress getAddress {get;set;}
    public ResponseGetAddress verifyAddress {get;set;}
    public ResponseGetAddress confirmAddress {get;set;}
    public ResponseGetAddress overrideAddress {get;set;}
    
    public string Street1{get;set;}
    public string street2{get;set;}
    public string city{get;set;}
    public string region{get;set;}
    public string pc{get;set;}


    
 // GET ADDRESS GET method
    
public PageReference  getaddressCallout(){
    
    
    
    HTTPRequest req= new HTTPRequest();
    HTTPResponse res= new HTTPResponse();
    HTTP h=new HTTP();

    req.setHeader('Authorization',authToken);
        
    req.setMethod('GET');    
    req.setEndpoint('https://api.trybambu.com//salesforceportal/account/address/' +acountId);    
   
    res=h.send(req);
     
        system.debug('Status code is ' +res.getStatusCode());
        system.debug('Status Body is ' +res.getBody());
        
        if(res.getStatusCode() == 200 && res.getBody()!= null) {
            getAddress = (ResponseGetAddress) json.deserialize(res.getBody(), ResponseGetAddress.class);
          
            if(getAddress.data.pending_address.is_valid == false && getAddress.data.pending_address.validation_msg!= null){
           
                ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Info, 
                                                           'Vadidation message states: '+getAddress.data.pending_address.validation_msg));          
            }
           
         
            if(getAddress.data.pending_address.user_Street1 == null){
           
                ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error, 
                                                        'No address present in pending address object'));          
            }
        }else {
            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'my error msg');
        }
        system.debug('Get Address log1 ' +getAddress);
    return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one of your problems is starting with your Query:

```
Account account = [SELECT Account__r.id FROM Pending_Address__c WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
```

--> I have a strong feeling, this query will never return anything.

Because: According to your code, I assume this is a custom controller for a visualforce page on the object "Pending_Address__c". If you open this, the Id in the url-parameter will always be a recordId of the current record, which is an object of Pending_Address__c."

Try something like this to get the AccountId.

```
String pendingAddressId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
Pending_Address__c pendingAddress= [SELECT Account__c
                                    FROM Pending_Address__c 
                                    WHERE Id = :pendingAddressId ];
accId  = pendingAddress.Account__c;
```

Just on the side. Please do not harcode your Token.

Comment: Hi ,

I appreciate your time!
This is in Dev right now and still working on it.

I tried to implement the code but it states "List has no rows for assignment to SObject"

Comment: String pendingAddressId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');

Above variable shows NULL value. Any advise?

Comment: What Link are you using to open the Visualforce Page? Do you have the id in your URL? Example: /apex/testpage?id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX .... replace the x'es with your recordID of an Pending_Address__c record. Here is a Salesforce help arcitcle explaining the same thing.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386885&type=1